# how to group ResultSet in Map by objects (java, jdbc)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Привет) У меня есть два класса, которые мне нужно создать, достав какие-то данные для них из дб:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product implements Replication<Product> {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long priceInCents;
    private int rate;

    public Product(String name, long priceInCents, int rate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    @Override
    public Product copy() {
        return new Product(id, name, priceInCents, rate);
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Category implements Replication<Category> {

    private long id;
    private String title;
    private List<Product> products;

    @Override
    public Category copy() {
        List<Product> copiedProducts = this.products.stream()
                .map(Product::copy)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new Category(id, title, copiedProducts);
    }
}
```

Достаю я их так ---> `select * from products p join categories c on p.category_id=c.category_id`

После выполнения запроса, они попадают в ResultSet. Как я могу обработать ResultSet, чтобы сделать как-нибудь из него стрим, в конечном итоге, создав все объекты? Может, есть вариант хоть как-то сгруппировать результат, чтобы предусмотреть, где кончается одна категория и начинается другая?

Например, желаемым результатом бы стала `Map<Category, List<Product>>`

Скрипты бд:

```
create database shop;

create table categories (
category_id bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
category_name varchar(100) not null
);

create table products(
        product_id bigint not null auto_increment primary key ,
        product_name varchar(100) not null ,
        price_in_cents bigint,
        rate int,
        category_id bigint not null ,
            constraint fk_products_categories
                foreign key (category_id) references categories(category_id)
        on delete cascade
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопросик решился. Если кому-то поможет, ничего имплементить не пришлось (сплитераторы и другое):

```
public List<Category> findAll() {
        String query = "select * from categories c join products p on c.category_id = p.category_id";

        Map<Category, List<Product>> groupedCategories = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        try (Connection connection = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)) {

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Category category = new Category();
                category.setId(resultSet.getLong("category_id"));
                category.setTitle(resultSet.getString("category_name"));

                if (!groupedCategories.containsKey(category)) {
                    groupedCategories.put(category, new ArrayList<>());
                }

                Product product = new Product();
                product.setId(resultSet.getLong("product_id"));
                product.setRate(resultSet.getInt("rate"));
                product.setName(resultSet.getString("product_name"));
                product.setPriceInCents(resultSet.getLong("price_in_cents"));

                groupedCategories.get(category).add(product);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return groupedCategories.entrySet().stream()
                .peek(entry -> entry.getKey().setProducts(entry.getValue()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```